# Snapchat style captions on recorded videos

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo and i am trying to implement a feature similar to snapchat/instagrams draw on video and add text/caption to video before upload it. My problem is not the UI part but editing the original video and getting a uri for the new video

I know with images you can use libraries like expo-pixi then take a snapshot of a view but i am not how to go about this for recorded videos specifically

anyone would be kind enough to point me to the right direction?